# Use func<> to return an int to database connector

Tags: c#

I am trying to return an integer parameter based on the incoming object type (entity in this case), but is uncertain of the format. Any help please?

```
entity.ID = db.Create(
                    entity.Name,
                    entity.Description,
                    entity.InitialStep != null ? (int?)entity.InitialStep.ID : null,
                    entity.IsPrivate,
                    entity.AllowOnBehalfSubmission,
                    new Func<int>{something needs to happen here and return an integer});
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want to pass a `Func<int>` to `db.Create`, and not just an `int`?

Comment: Some logic within Func<int> will need to return the integer equivelant of the object. So I am merely passing the result of Func to db.Create()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda function you're trying to call needs to be executed in the same context as the definition. By my understanding your object (entity) can be of several types and you want to set a parameter value based the object type? If so, modify your code along the following lines:

```
entity.ID = db.Create(
    entity.Name,
    entity.Description,
    entity.InitialStep != null ? (int?)entity.InitialStep.ID : null,
    entity.IsPrivate,
    entity.AllowOnBehalfSubmission,
    new Func<Type, int?> (type => 
    {
        if (type == typeof(SomeType))
            return 1;
        if (type == typeof(AnotherType))
            return 2;
        return null;
    })(entity.GetType())
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet FarligOpptreden. You should actually include the GetType() method after type. example: type.GetType() == typeof(SomeType)

Comment: That's indeed correct. You need to compare two typeof()s with one another. Well spotted!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a function that returns an int through several methods:

1) Specify an existing method

```
    private int MethodReturningInt() { return 1; }

    db.Create( /* ... */
             MethodReturningInt);  // note: no () !
```

2) Use a delegate (anonymous method)

```
    db.Create( /* ... */
      delegate() { return 1; });
```

3) Use a lambda expression

```
    db.Create(/* ... */
      () => 1);
```

Now you still need to adjust that returned value (1) to your needs ...